# python Make DataFrame available to other terminals of the server

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted the pandas dataframe stored in cache to be available in other terminals of same server.
I checked many posts which have answers to share data between child processes created by one parent process but seems they are not accessible across all the terminals of the server.

I tried using `SharedArray` module which creates references in `/dev/shm` filesystem and other terminals could also use the cache.
 For example:

```
import numpy as np
import SharedArray as sa

a = sa.create("shm://test", 10)
b = sa.attach("shm://test")
```

**However, the above method has a limitation where it can only hold a `numpy` array with less than 32 elements.

As mentioned, I'm trying to share a huge dataframe.**

Is this possible in python, if yes, please share any references?

Why I need this?
I'm creating a data frame which is built on hetrogenous data tables and is used for analytics of my organization.
This dataframe is cleansed and processed where complex operations can be completed very fast.